# Laravel relationship multiple where has

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Let's say i have this DB structure:

```
Table A:
-id
-user_id

Table B:
-id
-user_id

Table C:
-id
-user_id

Users:
-id
```

This is my User Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','username','password'];

    /**
     * Relationships
     */

    public function tableA()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\TableA::class);
    }
    public function tableB()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\TableB::class);
    }
    public function tableC()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\TableC::class);
    }
    public function tableD()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\TableD::class);
    }

}
```

This is what i want to achieve:

```
public function tables()
{
    // return all records from all 3 tables (Table A, Table B, Table C)
}
```

The way I can get a certain information on a table is by defining a relationship within the User model, saying it hasOne record of TableA, TableB, etc. However, I'm searching for a way to find on which of these tables (a,b,c,d) there is a Fk of User, following the same concept of relationships.

Note: Polymorphism is not a solution in this case

Comment: what you have tried for this issue?

Comment: Please add some more context - especially, how is this question related to Laravel after all?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama until now, i'm making single relatioships and calling them, but i'm looking for a simple and efficient way to achieve this, an all in one of sort.

Comment: @NicoHaase its a laravel project with eloquent relations, why this not related with laravel? Should i tag it with node js?

Comment: If you tag a question with a specific technology, you should provide context for it. If the only problem is reading the foreign keys from an existing database, the only technology involved might be the database system. If I got you wrong, please add the source code that is involved

Comment: Please share sample data and the expected output - receiving all records from three distinct tables should not be that hard, but that would completely lack the connection between these records

Answer (score 1):

Use an Eloquent local scope to achieve what you are trying to do:

`class User
{
    public function scopeAllTables($query)
    {
         return $query->join('table_a', 'table_a.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                      ->join('table_b', 'table_b.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                      ->join('table_c', 'table_c.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                      ->select('users.*')
                      ->addSelect('table_a.id AS table_a_id')
                      ->addSelect('table_b.id AS table_b_id')
                      ->addSelect('table_c.id AS table_c_id');
    }
}`

And in your controller, you can call this like:

`$allTables = User::allTables()->get();`

Comment: ty for your time, sounds like it works but i'm searching for eager loading

Answer (score 1):

If you want User records which have data in All other tables (i.e. TableA, TableA,etc. ), you can use below query as you already defined relationship :

```
$users = User::whereHas('tableA')
             ->whereHas('tableB')
             ->whereHas('tableC')
             ->get();
```

And if you want to access data of a related table you can use below query :

```
 $users = User::with('tableA','tableB','tableC')
              ->whereHas('tableA')
              ->whereHas('tableB')
              ->whereHas('tableC')
              ->get();
```

Comment: ty for your time, this works, but i was expecting something more abstract, more codeless. So far, this is the best answer, but i'll not accept it in order to find a better and clean way (at least for now).
Btw, your eloquent has to be orWhereHas in order to get all tables.